# How do I include all files within a folder hierarchy in an iOS bundle, but not include the folders themselves?

Tags: ios, xcode, nsfilemanager, nsbundle

I would like to be able to include files which an external tool created within my iOS build process so that the resources are placed into the bundle. This would be a good use for a folder reference, but I do not want these resources in a sub-directory, but rather flattened strait into the bundle like the other resources placed into groups within the bundle. This way, the resources could still be found using:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:extension];
```

Is there a way to do this without a post build script?

Answer (score 1):

I have not found an answer outside of a post build script, and the post build script method seems to work very easily and reliable. Here is the "Run Script" I added to XCode

```
find /${SRCROOT}/../ResourceTreeRoot/ -iname '*' -exec cp \{\} ${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}.app/ \;
```